# Usage of Ti.UI.Tray

Tags: operating-system, system-tray, tidesdk

Can Someone explain me what Ti.UI.Tray is for? I want to create a system tray application that displays notifications on update and when the user closes the window it goes into system tray instead of exiting and the user closes the application by explicitly choosing to exit. Can Ti.UI.Tray be used for this? If not, is there any other way to make a tidesdk system tray application for each of the windows,osx and linux platforms

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652830/how-to-make-tidesdk-window-not-closeable